# How to make this problem combinatorial and challenging?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have 9 positive real numbers

\begin{align}&SNR_{11},SNR_{12},SNR_{13}\\&SNR_{21},SNR_{22},SNR_{23}\\&SNR_{31},SNR_{32},SNR_{33}
\end{align}

The question is how can I intelligently find the indices $i,j,k,m,n,o,p,s,t$ such that

$$SNR_{1i} \geq max\{SNR_{1m}, SNR_{1n}\} $$
$$SNR_{2j}  \geq max\{ SNR_{2o}, SNR_{2p}\} $$
$$SNR_{3k} \geq max\{ SNR_{3s}, SNR_{3t}\} $$
$$ i,j,k \in\{1,2,3\} \,\,\,\,\,\, i\neq j \neq k$$
$$m,n \in\{1,2,3\} \,\,\,\,\,\, m,n\neq i \,\,\,\,\,\, m\neq n$$
$$o,p \in\{1,2,3\} \,\,\,\,\,\, o,p\neq j \,\,\,\,\,\, o\neq p$$
$$s,t \in\{1,2,3\} \,\,\,\,\,\, s,t\neq k \,\,\,\,\,\, s\neq t$$

Additional Condition if $SNR_{1i=b}$ wins in first row and $SNR_{2j=b}$ wins in the second row and $SNR_{3k=b}$ where $b\in\{1,2,3\}$ then the $\max\{SNR_{1i=b},SNR_{2i=b},SNR_{3i=b}\}$ has the priority to win to take over index $b$.

I don't want to go over numerical exhaustive search, I am looking for any intelligent idea (no matter how simple it might be) to speed up my search.
For example, can I eliminate search space, if I can satisfy one condition, then I wouldnt have to look over that index in the next condition?

If  you feel this problem doesn't make any sense, can anyone think of a way to make it more interesting (challenging, combinaorial)?

Looking forward for your help and/ or ideas.

Comment: It seems like you might not be able to even find indices in general.  It must be that $SNR_{1i}$ is the largest of the first row and so on, but there is no guarantee that the largest element will be greater than the sum of the others.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed the conditions. If that doesnt work too, what should be relaxed in your opinion so that I can have a clear problem

Comment: You have 3 similar problems, each per row, i.e. 3 numbers, since there is no visible link between the rows. If there is a solution it is only few options to try, nothing more simple or intelligent is required, because these are only 3 numbers - you can try all 3 options if you find what you need before. For a revised question it become even simple, this is just a maximum in a row, i.e. $a>max{b,c}$ is equivalent to find $max{a,b,c}$ and verify isn't equal to other 2.

Comment: thanks...i thought that the conditions on the indices should  couple the three row am i correct?

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the greater or equal sign. But realize that $i,j,k$ can not be equal... doesnt this complicate the problem?

Comment: @MorganRodgers if $SNR_{11}$ wins over in the first row and $SNR_{21}$ wins over the second row then we have problem, why do you think nothing couple the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $m,n,s,t,o,p$ don't matter at all.  Once you assign $i,j,k$, they just get the leftovers.  So all you are trying to find is $i,j,k$, with
$$SNR_{1i} = max\{SNR_{11}, SNR_{12}, SNR_{13}\}$$
$$SNR_{2j} = max\{SNR_{21}, SNR_{22}, SNR_{23}\}$$
$$SNR_{3k} = max\{SNR_{31}, SNR_{32}, SNR_{33}\}$$
such that $i$, $j$, and $k$ are all distinct (I think is what you meant by your equation).  You only have a decision to make about $i$,$j$, and $k$ if more than one entry in some row takes the maximum value.  You may or may not have a solution, there is probably nothing to do but test (there will be a maximum of six possibilities).